# CentOS 7 SMB server - Other Computer Cannot Connect To New Shares

Tags: linux, server-message-block

**How do I get the SMB server to work on CentOS 7 when sharing a folder on another volume?**

I have an up-to-date CentOS 7 computer and install `smb` with `yum`.

I added a share:

```
[LowSideScratch]
    path = /Volumes/K7_PDISK1/Shared/LowSideScratch
    available = yes
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    public = yes
    valid users = chrisadmin
    write list = *
    create mode = 0666
    directory mode = 0777
    inherit acls = yes
```

(It has a *lot* of fluff, I know, but it didn't used to; I've been trying to make it work).

I tried connecting to this server both from OS X and Windows 10. Both devices can access the default home share while authenticated as me (so my `smbpasswd` is correctly set up) but when they mount the `LowSideScratch` they can't see the `test.txt` file in there nor can they write any file to it.

I'm at a complete loss. I've spent an hour now searching and trying different combinations of settings and I just can't get it to work.

Some useful information:

```
[chrisadmin@k7-local ~]$ mount | grep Volumes
/dev/sda1 on /Volumes/K7_PDISK1 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
[chrisadmin@k7-local ~]$ ls -la /Volumes/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root       root         23 Aug 10  2017 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root       root        271 Aug 10  2017 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  6 chrisadmin chrisadmin 4096 Aug 10  2017 K7_PDISK1
[chrisadmin@k7-local ~]$ ls -la /Volumes/K7_PDISK1/
total 23585972
drwxrwxrwx. 6 chrisadmin chrisadmin        4096 Aug 10  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root       root                23 Aug 10  2017 ..
drwx------. 2 root       root             16384 May 31 04:12 lost+found
drwxrwxr-x. 3 chrisadmin chrisadmin        4096 Aug 10  2017 Shared
<other items redacted>
[chrisadmin@k7-local ~]$ ls -la /Volumes/K7_PDISK1/Shared/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x. 3 chrisadmin chrisadmin 4096 Aug 10  2017 .
drwxrwxrwx. 6 chrisadmin chrisadmin 4096 Aug 10  2017 ..
drwxrwxrwx. 2 chrisadmin chrisadmin 4096 Aug 10  2017 LowSideScratch
[chrisadmin@k7-local ~]$ ls -la /Volumes/K7_PDISK1/Shared/LowSideScratch/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx. 2 chrisadmin chrisadmin 4096 Aug 10  2017 .
drwxrwxr-x. 3 chrisadmin chrisadmin 4096 Aug 10  2017 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root       root          3 Aug 10  2017 test.txt
[chrisadmin@k7-local ~]$ cat /etc/fstab | grep Volumes
LABEL=K7_PDISK1 /Volumes/K7_PDISK1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Edit:

Apparently I can't read/write from the default shares either, but I can see a top-level folder listing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was with SELinux - the security subsystem that does filesystem protection.

The SE Linux Troubleshooter lists out all the things it learned and steps to enable it, which is helpful. However, I never did successfully make it enable access for the entirety of certain directories, so I had to make it enable RW access for `smbd` everywhere (and trust `smbd` to not have a bug to expose everything else); I'm not sure how I feel about this.

Then again, I was going to enable `smbd` without SELinux, so....